# KVM - Guest does not recognize second NIC

Tags: 12.10, networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a server running Proxmox (a virtualization platform), and created a KVM virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 12.10. After configuring the network, everything works fine, but if I add a second network adapter to that virtual machine, it is not recognized. `dmesg | grep -i eth` just shows one interface (eth0).

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Rebooting the machine is not enough, stopping the VM and starting it again is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Load the following kernel modules in the guest to enable **hot-plugging** of devices in KVM:

```
modprobe acpiphp
modprobe pci_hotplug
```

Add them as two separate lines in `/etc/modules` (without the `modprobe` part) to enable them permanently. This is Debian/Ubuntu specific as most other distributions (like CentOS/RedHat/Fedora/SUSE) build the kernel with these modules built-in. For Debian/Ubuntu you'll always have to load these modules yourself, unfortunately.

See also (block devices and network devices aren't really much different in this aspect):

- [KVM and Libvirt - How do I hotplug a new virtio disk?](https://serverfault.com/a/457259/135437)
- [Adding Virtio block devices at runtime in Libvirt KVM](https://serverfault.com/a/453463/135437)